# Protecting actions with email confirmation token?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

Let's say I have a user with his `email` in my database and he wants to send money to another user. But I want to confirm that action by sending an e-mail for confirmation after validations, to provide robust security for critic endpoints.

How can I achieve this with in a simpler and extendible way?

```
[HttpPost("SendMoney")]
public object SendMoney(int amount, int toUserId) {

    // check balance etc...

    SendConfirmationMail()
}
```

Comment: I’m afraid this question is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow. You could check ASP.NET Core Identity to see how they are creating account confirmation tokens that can be sent via email. You would essentially have to do this yourself for your action confirmation tokens. You could then later implement the confirmation token usage as an authentication requirement and use the `AuthorizationService` to check against it when you need it.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.